# Issue in calling a javascript function in C# using HtmlPage.Window.Invoke

Tags: javascript, c#, multithreading

Existing code :

```
public void HardwareConnectionComleted()
{

// some lines of code
string Details=new string[20];
Details=GetHardwareDetails(paramter);
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("RequestForDisplay",
                                   new object[] {Details});
}

public string[] GetHardwareDetails(parameter)
{
    // Some lines of code
    // some function calls
    return ...
 }
```

Code needed for the prototype :

```
public void HardwareConnectionComleted()
 {

  // some lines of code
  string Details=new string[20];
  Details=GetHardwareDetails(paramter);
  HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("RequestForDisplay",
                                   new object[] {Details});
  // I need 6 seconds delay   
   new System.Threading.Timer(obj => NewHardwareDetails(parameter), null, 6000,       System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
   }
 public string[] GetHardwareDetails(parameter)
{
  // Some lines of code
  // some function calls
  return..
}

public string[] NewHardwareDetails(parameter)
{
   String Details=new string[20];   
   // all the values are hardcoded
   HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("RequestForDisplay",
                                    new object[] {Details});
}
```

I need to pass 2 hardware details, with a delay of 6 seconds.
in the above syntax i got an exception : This operation can only occur on the UI Thread.

Before doing this experiment , I had tried the same logic in javascript (RequestForDisplay) function using

```
setTimeout(function () { HWdetails(Details); }, 6000);
```

I need a similar effect in C#.
I am new to this technology. Please suggest me some ideas on these.

Thank you